# python regex select all after expression

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make an regex search that will get all text after expressio.

I use the `(?<=%([\s\S]*?):\s).*$` regex but in python it not work.

**Example:**

`group-6-54574` is a dynamic text.

`May 12 2021 11:07:56 %group-6-54574: some text that i need`

**Return:**

```
some text that i need
```

**Main condition:**

Select all after text beetwen `%` and `:/s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `re` does not support an infinite length quantifier in a lookbehind assertion.

If you have the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/), you can use the pattern, and omit the capture group.

```
import regex
pattern = r"(?<=%[\s\S]*?:\s).*$"
s = ("group-6-54574 - it is a dynamic text\n\n"
     "May 12 2021 11:07:56 %group-6-54574: some text that i need")

print(regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['some text that i need']
```

---

Using `re`, you could use a capture group instead of a lookbehind.

```
%[\s\S]*:\s(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EQdIkE/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"%[\s\S]*:\s(.+)"
s = ("group-6-54574 - it is a dynamic text\n\n"
     "May 12 2021 11:07:56 %group-6-54574: some text that i need")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['some text that i need']
```

A bit more stricter pattern could be using a negated character class `[^%:]` to prevent some bracktracking

```
%[^%:]*:\s(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ziAEOr/1)